# how to find the previous date value based on 3 columns in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to find out the previous date value in my target table based on 3 columns. The example and scenario is explained in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: SELECT id, function_id,key, (select top 1 date from sourcetable where date < ST.date  order by date desc) From SourceTable ST

Comment: in Hive top function doesn't work. Also i tried using LIMIT 1 clause its giving me below error.   "Subqueries are not supported in the select list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `lag`.

```
select t.*,lag(date) over(partition by id,function_id,key order by date) as prev_date
from tbl t
```

Comment: can u pls help me with this as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831735/find-the-difference-in-days-from-previous-timestamp-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below works for you.

```
> create table vimarsh (id int, function_id int, key string, dt date);

> insert into vimarsh 
select 123,342,'test1','2018-10-15'
union all 
select 1234,35434,'test2','2018-10-16'
union all
select 2131,8907,'test3','2018-10-17'
union all
select 123,342,'test1','2018-10-18';

> select * from vimarsh;

+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--+
| vimarsh.id  | vimarsh.function_id  | vimarsh.key  | vimarsh.dt  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--+
| 123         | 342                  | test1        | 2018-10-15  |
| 1234        | 35434                | test2        | 2018-10-16  |
| 2131        | 8907                 | test3        | 2018-10-17  |
| 123         | 342                  | test1        | 2018-10-18  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--+

>  select id, function_id,key, dt, lag(dt) over(partition by id,function_id,key order by dt) as prev_date from vimarsh;
INFO  : OK
+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------+--+
|  id   | function_id  |  key   |     dt      |  prev_date  |
+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------+--+
| 123   | 342          | test1  | 2018-10-15  | NULL        |
| 123   | 342          | test1  | 2018-10-18  | 2018-10-15  |
| 1234  | 35434        | test2  | 2018-10-16  | NULL        |
| 2131  | 8907         | test3  | 2018-10-17  | NULL        |
+-------+--------------+--------+-------------+-------------+--+
4 rows selected (35.585 seconds)
```