# Find the difference in days from previous timestamp in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to find the days difference and populate a new column in my target table. The difference is created by subtracting the previous date from current date.

Please find the attached screen shot for reference.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: What is the DBMS?

Comment: Its Hive- Hadoop

Comment: Try using window functions `lead, lag`

Answer (score 1):

Using `LAG` function help you to get the previous row and `DATEDIFF` to get the difference.

```
select
    id,
    function_id,
    key,
    pre_date,
    datediff(pre_date, lag(pre_date, 1) over(order by id)) as days_difference
from
    [Your_Table]
```